# Add a country field to Django-Oscar address form

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-oscar

How can I add a coutry field to shipping address form in django oscar so i can later use it in CheckoutSessionMixin by calling a method
Documentation doesnt specify the form structure.
When I call the method I get the default value of "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland"
`self.get_shipping_address(basket)`
[image: Form]

Answer (score 2):

the first thing you should do is:

```
pip install pycountry
python manage.py oscar_populate_countries
```

then check the method **adjust_country_field**  in https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/src/oscar/apps/checkout/forms.py

basically list all countries with **is_shipping_country=True** (table: address_country) and "No need to show country dropdown if there is only one option"